# How to divide a set into K subsets such that the sum of the elements in the subsets are minimal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I'm studying DP and this problem came up to me when I was reading the Balanced Partition algorithm. In this algorithm we can divide a list in two lists such the sum of the elements of these lists are equal. But what if I need K lists and I need them to have a minimal sum? I thought of modifying the Balanced Partition algorithm to solve this, but I actually couldn't see a way to do this.

Let S be {1,1,5}, the optimal solution for K = 2 would be {1,1}, {5}.

Any hints? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but isn't sum of `{1,1} = 2` and sum of `{5} = 5` and therefore not equal?

Comment: @SethKitchen You've used 5 twice.

Comment: Also sets cannot contain duplicates so the example is invalid.

Comment: What? If I declare a set of socks. I have 3 green socks and 3 blue socks the set is {3,3}

Comment: Yeah...The main question is how to divide a set into K subsets such the sum of elements in these subsets are minimal. I've mentioned the Balanced Partition algorithm because it does something close to it. The example I gave was intended to explain a solution to the main question, not to exemplify the Balanced Partition (in this case, yeah, would not find a solution because 2 != 5).

Comment: Edited 'sets' to lists for convenience

Comment: Could you try to further explain what you want to minimise? I mean, consider your example, using lists `{1}` and `{1, 5}` gives minimal sum of elements for the first list (assuming empty lists are prohibited). BTW instead of taking about lists you could call them multisets, though I think it's clear what you mean when you use "list" here.

Comment: Sounds like this is still basically the same problem--at least if I understand your intent, you're still trying to divide into N groups with as close to equal sums as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm would be:

```
sort S in descending order
for each element in S:
    put it into the partition with the smallest sum
```

This would put `5` into the first partition and the `1`s into the second partition in your example (K=2).